# ASP.NET Core - Undefined function inside the loop html input element

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

```
function fillDatatable() {
    var PurchaseOrder = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@ViewBag.purchaseOrder));

    if (PurchaseOrder != "") {
        var tableHTML = '';

        $.each(PurchaseOrder, function (index, value) {
             tableHTML += "<tr>";
             tableHTML += "<td>" + value.items.itemID + "</td>";
             tableHTML += "<td>" + value.items.itemModelDescription + "</td>";
             tableHTML += "<td>";
             tableHTML += "<input id='UnitPrice" + value.items.ItemID + "' class='form-control b-r-xl text-right' value='" + value.items.itemUnitPrice + "' oninput='return change_unitprice(" + value.items.itemID + ")' />";
             tableHTML += "</td>";
             tableHTML += "<td>";
             tableHTML += "  </tr>";
         });

         $("#TableRecords").html(tableHTML);
     }
 }
```

I got stuck for almost 3 hrs doing this one. How would I fix this? I'm always thinking that there's nothing wrong with my concatenating the string and the function inside. But I'm getting undefined on oninput function even though the value of the ID is appearing, why is that?

Edited:

```
function change_unitprice(id) {
    window.alert(id);
}
```

This is my simple function on change unitprice if you are looking for this

Rendered HTML:

```
<tbody id="TableRecords">
     <tr>
          <td>ITM00000003</td><td>HPLJ PRO 400</td>
          <td>
               <input id="UnitPriceundefined" class="form-control b-r-xl text-right" value="35000" oninput="return change_unitprice(ITM00000003)">
          </td>
          <td></td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Hi @Jeffrey Estrera, can you attach the code for `change_unitprice` function  in your question. And you may refer to [onInput event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput]. As onInput is an event, you don't need to apply `return` in your `onInput` event. Thank you.

Comment: Please see my edited post

Comment: Even though I already removed the return in my onInput event, I'm still getting the same error. But im sure that I returned the value of the PurchaseOrder according to the console. So I think it's my concantenation is my problem. But I already search for correct way for that but still getting the same error.

Comment: you have both  value.items.ItemID and  value.items.itemID (in one item is capitalized)

Comment: Hi @jeffreyEstrera, you may refer to [code snippet](https://plnkr.co/edit/av1wIaYILz9TqDkN?open=lib%2Fscript.js). From here (with temporary hardcode data), I don't see any issue. Please ensure that your returned JSON, the JSON property naming are correct. Don't hesitate to ask again with additional information in the question. Good luck & thank you.

Comment: @BryanDellinger hello sir. I'm sorry don't get it. Please I need clarification.

Comment: Hi @JeffreyEstrera , you can press f12 to see the generated html code, check if the input rendered correctly.

Comment: Can you provided the *rendered* html, not the source.

Comment: Can you confirm exactly where/what the issue is?  Is it an error while rendering/generating the page?  Or does the page render ok, but when you click it gives "undefined function"? If that's the case, *exactly* where is `change_unitprice` defined?  It needs to be at the global/window level, if it's in doc.ready it won't find it. As tagged [jquery] (and assuming renders ok) please provide a [mcve] snippet (edit and click `[<>]`) that *demonstrates* the issue.  There's not enough included in the question.

Comment: page render is totally fine. What exactly my problem is. When you type on textbox which is rendered by html ( change_unitprice)  <Uncaught ReferenceError: ITM00000001 is not defined>       <--- it is giving me an error like this, also my change_unitprice function is already a global level.

Comment: Please see the rendered html above. @freedomn-m

Comment: You need quotes to hold the `ITM00000001`, without quotes it treats as variable. Thus you are getting ITM00000001 not defined.

Comment: Issue is clear from the rendered output:  `oninput="return change_unitprice(ITM00000003)">`  - what's `ITM0003`?  It's `undefined`.  It needs to be quoted.    This wasn't clear in the source as `value.items.itemID` looks like an `int`.  Change to `oninput='return change_unitprice(\"" + value.items.itemID + "\")'`

Comment: Separately, your rendered html also shows the issued mentioned by @BryanDellinger `id="UnitPriceundefined"` `id='UnitPrice" + value.items.ItemID + "'` should be `id='UnitPrice" + value.items.itemID + "'`

Comment: @freedomn-m hey bruh demn you save my day! so just as i thought I'm really wrong with string concateration.